# C++ String Error

Tags: c++

I got a code with an error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char'

```
std::string zipZap(const std::string& str){
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
        if (str[i] == 'z'){
            if (str[i+2] == 'p'){
                str[i+1] = "";
            }
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: The function name can't have spaces. Also - change `""` in the most-inner `if` to `''`.

Comment: `std::string zip zap` o.o that compiles!? also, calling a variable with the same name as a type is not such a good idea

Comment: You're accessing characters out of bounds of your string. You iterate `i` up to the last character, which is fine if you access that character using `str[i]`. But then you access the two following characters using `str[i+2]` and `str[i+1]`, which is invalid (undefined behavior).

Answer (score 3):

const string cant be modified. If you want to modify the string remove const from it.

And also you are assigning string to char index of string `string[i+1] = ""`

Instead it should be `string[i+1] = ' '` or `string[i+1] = '\0'`

Comment: After done that, it gave me an error: empty character constant

Answer (score 1):

```
const std::string& string
```

string is const, you cannot modify it like `string[i+1] = "";`

Comment: Even if it was non-const assigning a pointer to a character type is illegal.

Comment: If so, how do I modify it? I did try to create a new string. For Example string a = string; then use string a.

Comment: @user3326237 Then make new string,  *build* it, then return it. As-written if the either of the last two chars in your string are `z` you're invoking undefined behavior. Personally I would just pass by-value, modify the param, and return it.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning this part of your code:

```
str[i+1] = "";
```

You need to keep in mind that `str[i+1]` is expecting a single `char`acter, yet you are assigning it an empty string, which is of type `char*`.

Using `str[i+1] = '\0';` will give you the result that you appear to be after. But in order for it to succeed you will need to change `const std::string& str` to `std::string& str` in your function's head.